# Multiple PO getting generated for multiple products in Single Indent

Tags: openerp-7

I am creating Indent of multiple products and each time Purchase order for every product is created.
I want single PO for multiple products given in Indent.

Example: Indent contains 3 products, then 3 different PO for that indent is created for every product respectively.

Need solution for this

Comment: want a single PO for single Indent

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output